# If a continuous function $f:(0, 1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $(0, 1)$ then $f(1/2)\leq \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If a continuous function $f:(0, 1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $(0, 1)$ then $f(1/2)\leq \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$. (T/F)

I think the statement is true but couldn't prove it. Please help to solve.

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^1f(t)dt=\int_0^1f(1-t)dt$

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is convex, for any $0 \le t \le 1$ you have
$\frac{1}{2} \left(f(t) + f(1-t)\right) \ge f(\frac{1}{2})$.  Now integrate both sides from $t = 0$ to $1$ and make some appropriate changes of variables.